# Laravel is it necessary to change the html to laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this in **html form**

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

is it necessary to change my code to:

```
 {{ Form::text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Username'))}}
            {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password'))}}
            {{ Form::password('confirmPassword', array('placeholder' => 'Confirm Password'))}}
            {{ Form::button('next', array('class' => 'next action-button'))}}
```

in order to submit?

or adding

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'restaurants.store', 'id' => 'msform')) }}
```

and

```
{{ Form::close() }}
```

at the beginning of the form and and the end of the form is enough to submit?

#### routes.php

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

#### RestaurantController.php

```
<?php

class RestaurantsController extends BaseController {
public function store()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

#### HTML from Chrome

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            Parking Project
        </div>

        <!-- end navigation -->
    </div>
    <div class="body">

<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/restaurants" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="msform"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="TUU8Us2X6qcvKiw8RpYSkrOA0Rui41EiLLG4XcWt"><!-- multistep form -->

        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
            <li class="active">Social Profiles</li>
            <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
            <li class="active">Address</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset style="opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); display: none;">
            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            <input placeholder="Username" name="email" type="text" value="">            <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">            <input placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword" type="password" value="">            <button class="next action-button" type="button">next</button>        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="display: none; left: 0%; opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);">
            <h2 class="fs-title">General Information</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your public profile</h3>
            <input type="text" name="restaurantName" placeholder="Restaurant Name">
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website">
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="display: none; left: 0%; opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);">
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number">
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="display: block; left: 0%; opacity: 1;">

            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script><script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/17/3/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <div id="map_manual_address_container">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"><div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%; cursor: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur) 8 8, default; -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 200;"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 201;"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 320px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 320px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 320px;"></div></div></div></div></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 202;"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 320px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 64px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 320px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: -192px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 320px;"></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 64px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264130614&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=72&amp;y=92&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 64px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264113486&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=71&amp;y=92&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: -192px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264101166&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=72&amp;y=91&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 131px; top: 320px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264133836&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=72&amp;y=93&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 64px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264000000&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=73&amp;y=92&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: -192px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264101176&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=71&amp;y=91&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: -192px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264101119&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=73&amp;y=91&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 387px; top: 320px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264012777&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=73&amp;y=93&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 320px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;"><img src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@264132093&amp;src=apiv3&amp;hl=en-US&amp;x=71&amp;y=93&amp;z=8&amp;style=47,37%7Csmartmaps" draggable="false" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);"></div></div></div></div></div><div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.5403,-78.5463&amp;z=8&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"><div style="width: 62px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white2.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 62px; height: 26px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></a></div><div class="gmnoprint" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 165px; bottom: 0px; width: 57px;"><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right;"><a style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">Map Data</a><span style="display: none;">Map data ©2014 Google</span></div></div></div><div style="padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 148px; position: absolute; left: 18px; top: 115px; background-color: white;"><div style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 16px;">Map Data</div><div style="font-size: 13px;">Map data ©2014 Google</div><div style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></div><div class="gmnoscreen" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); direction: ltr; text-align: right; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">Map data ©2014 Google</div></div><div class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc" draggable="false" style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; -webkit-user-select: none; right: 95px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right;"><a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Terms of Use</a></div></div><div draggable="false" class="gm-style-cc" style="-webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right;"><a target="_new" title="Report errors in the road map or imagery to Google" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.5403,-78.5463&amp;z=8&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3&amp;skstate=action:mps_dialog$apiref:1&amp;output=classic" style="font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; position: relative;">Report a map error</a></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" draggable="false" controlwidth="32" controlheight="84" style="margin: 5px; -webkit-user-select: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div controlwidth="32" controlheight="40" style="cursor: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur) 8 8, default; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="width: 32px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -9px; top: -102px; width: 1028px; height: 214px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div style="width: 32px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -107px; top: -102px; width: 1028px; height: 214px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div style="width: 32px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -58px; top: -102px; width: 1028px; height: 214px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div style="width: 32px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -205px; top: -102px; width: 1028px; height: 214px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" controlwidth="0" controlheight="0" style="opacity: 0.6; display: none; position: absolute;"><div title="Rotate map 90 degrees" style="width: 22px; height: 22px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -38px; top: -360px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" controlwidth="20" controlheight="39" style="position: absolute; left: 6px; top: 45px;"><div style="width: 20px; height: 39px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -39px; top: -401px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div title="Zoom in" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 2px; width: 20px; height: 17px; cursor: pointer;"></div><div title="Zoom out" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 19px; width: 20px; height: 17px; cursor: pointer;"></div></div></div><div class="gmnoprint" style="margin: 5px; z-index: 0; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; right: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="gm-style-mtc" style="float: left;"><div draggable="false" title="Show street map" style="direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 1px 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; min-width: 22px; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-clip: padding-box;">Map</div><div style="z-index: -1; padding-top: 2px; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 19px; text-align: left; display: none; background-color: white; background-clip: padding-box;"><div draggable="false" title="Show street map with terrain" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 3px 8px 3px 3px; direction: ltr; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="checkbox" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); border-top-left-radius: 1px; border-top-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-left-radius: 1px; width: 13px; height: 13px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: -2px; width: 13px; height: 11px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -44px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 68px; height: 67px;"></div></span><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">Terrain</label></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-mtc" style="float: left;"><div draggable="false" title="Show satellite imagery" style="direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative; color: rgb(86, 86, 86); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 1px 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; min-width: 38px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-clip: padding-box;">Satellite</div><div style="z-index: -1; padding-top: 2px; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 19px; text-align: left; display: none; background-color: white; background-clip: padding-box;"><div draggable="false" title="Zoom in to show 45 degree view" style="color: rgb(184, 184, 184); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 3px 8px 3px 3px; direction: ltr; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="checkbox" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid rgb(241, 241, 241); border-top-left-radius: 1px; border-top-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-left-radius: 1px; width: 13px; height: 13px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: -2px; width: 13px; height: 11px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -44px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 68px; height: 67px;"></div></span><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">45°</label></div><div draggable="false" title="Show imagery with street names" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; padding: 3px 8px 3px 3px; direction: ltr; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="checkbox" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); border-top-left-radius: 1px; border-top-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-left-radius: 1px; width: 13px; height: 13px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: -2px; width: 13px; height: 11px; overflow: hidden;"><img src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -44px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 68px; height: 67px;"></div></span><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">Labels</label></div></div></div></div></div></div>
                    <div id="mamual_address">
                        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit">
            <input class="submit action-button" type="submit" value="submit">       </fieldset>

</form>    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your controller and the generated HTML from your form (open the page with the form in your browser and copy/paste the page's source code).

Comment: @André I just did what you have asked for.

Comment: What's the problem exactly ? What do you mean by "is not submitting" ? And it's normal if your controller is really empty (if it's not then please post the complete controller).

Comment: @André I mean that when clicking on submit, nothing happens, and the controller is not empty, i has too many functions, but the function `store` is yes empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not laravel code. Its just blade, its a templating engine that just makes writing HTML easier for you. While its recommended that you use blade to create your views, it is not at all necessary.

Comment: but it seems that it is not working when submit, that is why I have asked here. do you know why is that happening ?

Comment: The form will work fine even when you write it in HTML. I have done it myself sometimes while prototyping. Have you properly checked your code? I would need to see your code to say anything for sure.

Comment: the form is not submiting even with html syntax. I will post the code for you.

Comment: I just updated the question with needed code. appreciate your time.

Comment: notice that I have added two submit button, one with html syntax and one with blade syntax just to try. but neither is working

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with your code. But as far as im concerned, the problem could be with your route. Have you defined POST controller for that route? OR try giving a url in the opening tag. 

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}

Comment: adding a url is not necessary, I have other form without url and it is working, and yes I have added a post function in my `RestaurantController` with is `public function store()
 {
  //
 }`

Comment: and I have the route like this `Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');` the route is working

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, it'll still work if the field names and the path match your POST route and your controller.

However, it's recommended and necessary for example when you need to [redirect to a page with the previous input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input) (in case of a validation error for example).

This :

`Redirect::to('form')->withInput();`

Will not work if your form is only an HTML form.

Also if you want to use the built-in [CSRF protection](http://laravel.com/docs/html#csrf-protection), it won't work with your HTML form unless you manually add a field with the `Form::token()` to your form, but when using Laravel's form helpers, that field is added automatically.

Comment: the form is not submiting, I don't know why, could you read the comments on the other answer, I have told the user the information needed.